# How do I limit the character Input range?

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-c++

The Problem states,

> The get_char subroutine allows any character to be entered.  Modify get_char, using assembly, to accept ASCII characters that are within the range of '0' and 'z' inclusively only.  You will additionally need to accept '$' as a valid input (the terminating character).  If an invalid character is entered, it should keep asking for a new input until one is given, additionally displaying the error message "Alphanumeric characters only, please try again > ".

```
void get_char(char& a_character)
{
  a_character=(char) _getwche();
  if (a_character=='0' || a_character=='z')  // allow the enter key to work as the terminating character too
    a_character=dollarchar;
}
```

Comment: If you are using assembly, why did you tag this as C++?

Comment: Oh yes. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the code in assembly, but in C the `get_char()` function you showed would need to look something more like the following:

```c
void get_char(char& a_character)
{
  do
  {
    a_character = (char) _getwche();
    if (
      ((a_character >= '0') && (a_character <= '9')) ||
      ((a_character <= 'a') && (a_character <= 'z')) ||
      ((a_character <= 'A') && (a_character <= 'Z')) ||
      (a_character == dollarchar)
      )
    /* alternatively:
    if (isalnum(a_character) || (a_character == dollarchar))
    */
    {
      break;
    }

    printf("Alphanumeric characters only, please try again > ");
  }
  while (true);
}
```

Alternatively:

```c
void get_char(char& a_character)
{
  a_character = (char) _getwche();
  while (
    !(
      ((a_character >= '0') && (a_character <= '9')) ||
      ((a_character <= 'a') && (a_character <= 'z')) ||
      ((a_character <= 'A') && (a_character <= 'Z')) ||
      (a_character == dollarchar)
      )
    )
  /* alternatively:
  while (!isalnum(a_character) && (a_character != dollarchar))
  */
  {
    printf("Alphanumeric characters only, please try again > ");
    a_character = (char) _getwche();
  }
}
```

I leave it as an exercise for you to translate the C code to assembly.